# KeyError: ‘touchAction’ in Appium with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, appium, appium-android

I am self learning Appium with Python, but unable to execute TouchAction as I’m facing error

> KeyError: ‘touchAction’.

Here are the details:

- Appium Version: 1.17.1
- IDE: Pycharm

**Code:**

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
from selenium import webdriver

# Define desired capabilities
desired_caps = {
    "deviceName": "ac******",
    "platformName": "Android",
    "appPackage": "com.android.dialer",
    "noReset": "true",
    "appActivity": "com.oneplus.contacts.activities.OPDialtactsActivity"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", desired_caps)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

# Locators and actions

user_action = TouchAction(driver)
user_action.tap(x=909, y=220).perform()
```

**Logs in PyCharm:**

```
C:\Users\PycharmProjects\AppiumSandbox\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/PycharmProjects/AppiumSandbox/tests/contactone.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:/Users/PycharmProjects/AppiumSandbox/tests/contactone.py”, line 21, in
user_action.tap(x=909, y=220).perform()
File “C:\Users\PycharmProjects\AppiumSandbox\venv\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\common\touch_action.py”, line 149, in perform
self._driver.execute(Command.TOUCH_ACTION, params)
File “C:\Users\PycharmProjects\AppiumSandbox\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py”, line 319, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File “C:\Users\PycharmProjects\AppiumSandbox\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py”, line 367, in execute
command_info = self._commands[command]
KeyError: ‘touchAction’
```

**Logs in Appium:**

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/f509a834-5b7e-4354-89d5-00dd4a59666d/timeouts

[HTTP] {“implicit”:20000}

[W3C (f509a834)] Calling AppiumDriver.timeouts() with args: [null,null,null,null,20000,“f509a834-5b7e-4354-89d5-00dd4a59666d”]

[BaseDriver] W3C timeout argument: {“implicit”:20000}}

[BaseDriver] Set implicit wait to 20000ms

[W3C (f509a834)] Responding to client with driver.timeouts() result: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved by adding `from appium import webdriver` and removing `from selenium import webdriver` under mentioned Automation script.